# Cambiar colores del input con JS

Tags: javascript

soy nueva en el mundo de la programación y estoy aprendiendo Javascript. Estoy haciendo un código que te permita elegir los colores de un dibujo en canvas, sin embargo, me gustaría poder hacerlo con condicionales if & else, aún así, he intentado pero no he podido hacerlo, me gustaría que me pudieran ayudar y decirme en qué estoy fallando.
Aquí el código en js

```
function colorpicking () {

var colorpicker = colorcito_uno.value;
var colorpicker2 = colorcito_dos.value;
var colorcito = "#5DBB95";
var colorcite = "#BBA65D";
colorpicker.addEventListener("input", updateFirst, false);
colorpicker.addEventListener("change", updateAll, false);
colorpicker2.addEventListener("input", updateFirst, false);
colorpicker2.addEventListener("change", updateAll, false);
colorpicker.select();
colorpicker.select();

if (colorpicker == colorcito_uno.value){
    dibujarlineas(colorcito_uno, xi, 400, 400, nyf);
    dibujarlineas(colorcito_uno, 0, yf, nxf, 0);
    dibujarlineas(colorcito_uno, 0, xf, 390, nyf);
}
else if (colorpicker2) {
    dibujarlineas(colorpicker2, 0, yi, xf, 400);
    dibujarlineas(colorpicker2, 400, yf, xi, 0);
    dibujarlineas(colorpicker2, xi, 0, nxf, 400);
}
else {
    dibujarlineas(colorcito, xi, 400, 400, nyf);
    dibujarlineas(colorcito, 0, yf, nxf, 0);
    dibujarlineas(colorcite, 0, yi, xf, 400);
    dibujarlineas(colorcite, 400, yf, xi, 0);
    dibujarlineas(colorcite, xi, 0, nxf, 400);
    dibujarlineas(colorcito, 0, xf, 390, nyf);
} }
```

Este es el html

```
<p>Cuántas lineas quieres <br>
    <input type="text" id="cajadetexto_lineas"/> 
    <input type="button" value="Enviar" id="boton"/><br>
    <p>Elige tus dos colores favoritos
    </p>
    <input type="color" id="colorcito_uno" value="#5DBB95" /><input type="color" value="#BBA65D" id="colorcito_dos" />

</p>
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="dibujito"></canvas>
<p>Así es cómo queda tu dibujo</p>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Borra el lienzo" id="boton_borrar"/>
<script src="dibujito-con-eventos.js"></script>
</center>
```

Y aquí está el [código completo](https://codepen.io/carolina78964/pen/ZELQarP)

Cómo ven, intento que la persona eliga el color y el número de lineas en las que quiere el dibujo, sin embargo, el código para cambiar de color no funciona.
¿Cómo se podría hacer con condicionales?

Comment: Bienvenida a SOes, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código, es más fácil analizarlo aquí que en un enlace externo y podrías recibir una respuesta adecuada más rápido.

Comment: Hay algún error que tengas en la consola? Y podrías mostrar el código que tienes con el cual cambias de color? Ya que solo hay funciones

Comment: Hola, sí. Todo está en el enlace ya que no me deja poner el código completo aquí!

Answer (score 1):

No hace falta ponerle ningún condicional más.

Para mí sería mejor cambiar los colores haciendo esto:

Agregarle a los dos `input type=color` un `onchange` y un `onkeyup` que sirven para llamar a una función que estará "escuchando" los cambios de color.

```
<input type="color" id="colorcito_uno" value="#5DBB95" onchange="cambio1(this)" onkeyup="cambio1(this)" />
<input type="color" value="#BBA65D" id="colorcito_dos" onchange="cambio2(this)" onkeyup="cambio2(this)" />
```

Luego en el JavaScript establecemos los valores por defecto de `colorcito_uno` y `colorcito_dos` por si el usuario no quiere cambiar los colores predeterminados.

```
//Variables de cambio de color///
var colorcito_uno = "#5DBB95"
var colorcito_dos = "#BBA65D"
```

Más abajo creamos las funciones `cambio1` y `cambio2` que van a estar "escuchando" los cambios de los `input type=color` actualizando el color al que elija el usuario.

```
function cambio1(t) {
 colorcito_uno = t.value
}
function cambio2(t) {
 colorcito_dos = t.value
}
```

Y por último, en la función `drawbyclick()` hay que cambiar los argumentos de todas las veces que se llama a la función `dibujarlineas()` según corresponda con `colorcito_uno` o `colorcito_dos`.

```
dibujarlineas(colorcito_uno, xi, 400, 400, nyf);
dibujarlineas(colorcito_uno, 0, yf, nxf, 0);
dibujarlineas(colorcito_dos, 0, yi, xf, 400);
dibujarlineas(colorcito_dos, 400, yf, xi, 0);
dibujarlineas(colorcito_dos, xi, 0, nxf, 400);
dibujarlineas(colorcito_uno, 0, xf, 390, nyf);
```

Haciendo todos esos cambios, se puede probar y creo que ahora funciona bien.

```js
//Variables de texto y botón///
var texto = document.getElementById("cajadetexto_lineas")
var boton = document.getElementById("boton")
boton.addEventListener("click", drawbyclick);

//Variables del lienzo///

var d = document.getElementById("dibujito");
var lienzo = d.getContext("2d");
var ancho = d.width;

//Variables de cambio de color///
var colorcito_uno = "#5DBB95"
var colorcito_dos = "#BBA65D"
var botonborrar = document.getElementById("boton_borrar")
botonborrar.addEventListener("click", borrarlienzo);
function cambio1(t) {
  colorcito_uno = t.value
}
function cambio2(t) {
  colorcito_dos = t.value
}

//Función de elegir color///
function colorpicking () {

    var colorpicker = colorcito_uno.value;
    var colorpicker2 = colorcito_dos.value;
    var colorcito = "#5DBB95";
    var colorcite = "#BBA65D";
  
    console.log("colorpicking" + colorcito_uno.value)
  
    colorpicker.addEventListener("input", updateFirst, false);
    colorpicker.addEventListener("change", updateAll, false);
    colorpicker2.addEventListener("input", updateFirst, false);
    colorpicker2.addEventListener("change", updateAll, false);
    colorpicker.select();
    colorpicker.select();


    
    if (colorpicker == colorcito_uno.value){
        dibujarlineas(colorcito_uno, xi, 400, 400, nyf);
        dibujarlineas(colorcito_uno, 0, yf, nxf, 0);
        dibujarlineas(colorcito_uno, 0, xf, 390, nyf);
    }
    else if (colorpicker2) {
        dibujarlineas(colorpicker2, 0, yi, xf, 400);
        dibujarlineas(colorpicker2, 400, yf, xi, 0);
        dibujarlineas(colorpicker2, xi, 0, nxf, 400);
    }
    else {
        dibujarlineas(colorcito, xi, 400, 400, nyf);
        dibujarlineas(colorcito, 0, yf, nxf, 0);
        dibujarlineas(colorcite, 0, yi, xf, 400);
        dibujarlineas(colorcite, 400, yf, xi, 0);
        dibujarlineas(colorcite, xi, 0, nxf, 400);
        dibujarlineas(colorcito, 0, xf, 390, nyf);
    }
}

//Función de borrar lienzo///
function borrarlienzo (){
    lienzo.clearRect(0,0,d.width,d.height);
}

//Función de dibujar con click///
function drawbyclick(){
    
    var z = parseInt(texto.value);
    var lineas = z;
    var l = 0;
    var yi, xf, xi, yf;
    var nyf, nxf;
    var space = ancho / lineas;
    

for (l=0; l < lineas; l++) {
    yi =  space * l;
    xf = space * (l+1);
    xi = space * l
    yf = space * (l+1);
    nxf = 400 - xf;
    nyf = 400 - yf;
    dibujarlineas(colorcito_uno, xi, 400, 400, nyf);
    dibujarlineas(colorcito_uno, 0, yf, nxf, 0);
    dibujarlineas(colorcito_dos, 0, yi, xf, 400);
    dibujarlineas(colorcito_dos, 400, yf, xi, 0);
    dibujarlineas(colorcito_dos, xi, 0, nxf, 400);
    dibujarlineas(colorcito_uno, 0, xf, 390, nyf);

}

}

//Función de dibujar///
function dibujarlineas (color, xinicial, yinicial, xfinal, yfinal)
{
lienzo.beginPath();
lienzo.strokeStyle = color;
lienzo.moveTo(xinicial,yinicial);
lienzo.lineTo(xfinal,yfinal);
lienzo.stroke();
lienzo.closePath();
}
```

```html
<body>
    <center>
    <h1>Dibujo en canvas</h1>
    <p>Cuántas lineas quieres <br>
        <input type="text" id="cajadetexto_lineas"/> 
        <input type="button" value="Enviar" id="boton"/><br>
        <p>Elige tus dos colores favoritos
        </p>
        <input type="color" id="colorcito_uno" value="#5DBB95" onchange="cambio1(this)" onkeyup="cambio1(this)" />
        <input type="color" value="#BBA65D" id="colorcito_dos" onchange="cambio2(this)" onkeyup="cambio2(this)" />

    </p>
    <canvas width="400" height="400" id="dibujito"></canvas>
    <p>Así es cómo queda tu dibujo</p>
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Borra el lienzo" id="boton_borrar"/>
    <script src="dibujito-con-eventos.js"></script>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si funciona. Sin embargo si me quedé con la duda de si era posible con condicionales, muchísimas gracias!